# Restrict line chart zoom in upto hours in dc chart library

Tags: javascript, d3.js, linechart, dc.js, crossfilter

We are facing issue with the line chart of dc library.

http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/

Take an example of above link where Monthly Index Abs is a line chart. When you zoom in, It goes upto minutes on X-Axis like  **5.15,  5.30, 5.45**  etc.

We have defined X-Axis scale like below: It is combination of Day,Month, Year and hour.

```
.x(d3.time.scale().domain([new Date(sdate.getFullYear(),sdate.getMonth(),sdate.getDate(),sdate.getHours()), new Date(edate.getFullYear(),edate.getMonth(),edate.getDate(),edate.getHours())])) // (startDate, endDate)
```

In this, We have tried to restrict zoom up to hours in two ways but its not working.

Approach 1:

```
 .zoomExtent([0, 23]);
```

Approach 2:

```
.zoomExtent([new Date(sdate.getFullYear(),sdate.getMonth(),sdate.getDate(),sdate.getHours()), new Date(edate.getFullYear(),edate.getMonth(),edate.getDate(),edate.getHours())]);
```

we would like to this zoom in functionality to restrict upto hours like  **4 pm, 5 pm, 6 pm**  etc and not upto minutes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`chart.zoomScale()`](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#zoomscaleextent), which is used to set [`d3.zoom.scaleExtent()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior#scaleExtent)

The parameter is an array with two elements, the minimum and maximum scaling allowed. By default it is `[1, Infinity]`

Determine the maximum factor by which you want the chart to scale and set. E.g. if you want it only to zoom 20x, set:

```
chart.zoomScale([1, 20]);
```

The scaling is a multiplicative factor. I.e. if there are 20 days in the zoomed out chart, setting the second element of the array to 20 will let you zoom in to 1 day, or setting it to 20*24 will allow you to zoom in to 1 hour, etc.

Comment: I have updated question. Can you please look into this ?

Comment: I have clarified above.

Comment: We tried your approach but it did not work for us. However, We  tried .zoomScale([1,12]) which resulted in what we want. Thanks for your effort. you can update your answer so that i can mark it as correct

Comment: Ah, sorry about that typo. I did link to the right thing! :-/ Thanks for the correction, will fix my answer now.

Comment: @Gordon 

chart.zoomScale([1, no. of days * 3]) worked in my case.